# Making a process non-blocking inside a websocket asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am using websocket library in python to communicate with a JS code in front end. Here is a summary of what I am doing. When I receive a message from the client, I call __process_msg, generate some output, and then send back the result to the client. The problem here is that __process_msg is time-consuming. While we are inside the __process_msg, I cannot serve any other requests from the clients. How can I make the __process_msg non-blocking?

```
def __start_webtool_server(self, server, ephemeral_port):

    log.info("Starting the Webtool server thread on %s:%s" % (server, ephemeral_port))

    graph_gui_thread = Thread(target=self.__start_webtool_server_run,
                              args=[server, ephemeral_port],
                              daemon=True)
    graph_gui_thread.start()
    return graph_gui_thread


def __start_webtool_server_run(self, server, ephemeral_port):

    try:
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.__start_webtool_server_async, server, ephemeral_port, max_size=None)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except Exception as E:
        log.error("Error: %s" % E)


async def __start_webtool_server_async(self, websocket, path):

        async for message in websocket:

            await self.__process_msg(message, websocket)


async def __process_msg(self, message, websocket):

    await self.__process_sub_msg(message, websocket)


async def __process_sub_msg(self, message, websocket):

    ### a long blocking processing here ......

    data_to_send = "blablabla"
    await websocket.send(data_to_send)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. It is still blocking!

Comment: What kind of work does `__process_msg`'s long processing do? Does it perhaps invoke some blocking/CPU-bound code?

Comment: I updated the sample code. The `__process_msg` calls another async method `__process_sub_msg` and within that method, I have normal blocking code. Specifically I am loading a huge YAML file with `yaml.safe_load` and its a taking a long time.

Comment: Ok - replace `yaml.safe_load(x)` with `await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, yaml.safe_load, x)` and see if that helps with your issue.

Comment: wow! that did the trick. Thanks a tone! You could add it as an answer, if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `__process_msg` is invoking CPU-bound or otherwise non-async (blocking) code, you should off-load it to a thread pool to avoid halting the event loop while the code is running. The easiest way to do that is to use the [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) event loop method:

```
async def __process_msg(self, message, websocket):
    #value = long_running_function(args...)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    value = await loop.run_in_executor(None, long_running_function, args...)
```